# Rails 5 API + React + CORS + Heroku + GH Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, cors

Morning all

Having a headbashing moment again and could use help.

I have a React client consuming a Rails 5 API. Everything was working great on localhost, working perfectly. I deployed the client to GH pages first and the API to Heroku but couldn't make post requests to the server, I keep getting the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/auth/login' from origin 'https://xxxx.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

The same request works fine from Postman, but now it's broken in localhost too so I can't do anything :-(

The issue is apparently CORS - I've tried multiple configurations but nothing seems to be making even a dent, as I keep getting the exact same error.

I have the `rack-cors gem`. My `application.rb` looks like this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any # also tried [:get, :post, etc]
  end
end
```

One odd thing is when I run `bundle exec rake middleware` I get 2 `use Rack::Cors` at the top of the list - can't seem to find out why.

I've tried manually setting the headers in `application_controller.rb`:

```
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers



def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
      cors_set_access_control_headers
      render text: '', content_type: 'text/plain'
    end
  end

  # protected
  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Credentials'
  end
```

I've tried a few other things, but still getting the same damn error. Some help would be awesome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you by any chance look into CSRF? Rails adds authenticity token to all your forms to validate origin of the request.
You need to disable the check for specific actions that will be accessed with requests from the outside of the application:

`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:update]` or other actions you need

Comment: I've got `skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: %i[login register]` in my users_controller.rb and getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - I somehow missed the blazingly obvious cors.rb file that had the wrong `origins` set up